# how do i save a bitmap object as a jpeg file in C#

Tags: bitmap, jpeg

I have a function that returns a bitmap object. How do i save such a object as a jpg file in C# ?

So far i have this code segment

```
b = MakeGrayscale(b);
b.Save("C:\\test.jpg");
```

I get this error message

{"A generic error occurred in GDI+."}

```
StackTrace

   at System.Drawing.Image.Save(String filename, ImageCodecInfo encoder, EncoderParameters encoderParams)
   at System.Drawing.Image.Save(String filename, ImageFormat format)
   at System.Drawing.Image.Save(String filename)
   at Convert.Program.Plot(Byte[]& fileBufferArray, Int32 fileSize, Int32 offset) in C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Convert\Convert\Program.cs:line 151
   at Convert.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Convert\Convert\Program.cs:line 42
   at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
   at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean ignoreSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
```

Could someone please help me?

Comment: Do you have write access?  Is the file in use?

Comment: Does the account running the application have permissions to create and save files on the root of your `c:` drive?

Comment: thanks. you were correct. I did not have permission to write.